# How to get Bigquery table's name inside a Stackdriver alert documentation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I've created a Stackdriver Monitoring alert to send me an email when one of my BigQuery tables increases its size more than 5% during the day. The alert is working fine, but I would like to receive information on what is the table that is triggering the alert.

I have tried several combinations that I have found in the [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables#doc-vars) but none of them work for me. Right now my documentation template looks like this:

```
resource.label.table: ${resource.label.table} --> Returns null

condition.name: ${condition.name}
condition.display_name: ${condition.display_name}
metric.type: ${metric.type}
metric.display_name: ${metric.display_name}
policy.name: ${policy.name}
policy.display_name: ${policy.display_name}
project: ${project}
resource.type: ${resource.type}
```

Does anyone know how to retrieve the table name?

Comment: What's the `resource.type`: is it `bigquery_dataset`? Does it work with `${metric.labels.table}`?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the list of [BigQuery metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-bigquery), the `resource.type` can be `global`, `bigquery_project` or `bigquery_dataset`. Metrics can include additional labels that can be accessed through [`metric.labels.[KEY]`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables#doc-vars). For example, the `storage/uploaded_row_count` metric reports `api` and `table`:

[image]

To test this we create an alerting policy that checks whenever rows are uploaded to a table:

[image]

Using the following documentation template with `${metric.labels.table}`:

```
## BigQuery uploaded rows alert

metric.labels.table: ${metric.labels.table}

---

condition.name: ${condition.name}

condition.display_name: ${condition.display_name}

metric.type: ${metric.type}

metric.display_name: ${metric.display_name}

policy.name: ${policy.name}

policy.display_name: ${policy.display_name}

project: REDACTED

resource.type: ${resource.type}
```

Then we load some rows to a BigQuery table and, when the metric data is available after ~6 hours, we should get the alert mail with the correct table name (`cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_20191223` in this case):

[image]

---

**EDIT**: it also works fine with the `bigquery.googleapis.com/storage/stored_bytes` metric:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Guillem!

I tried your code and it's not working for me. The main difference is that I am using another Metric (stored_bytes) but it also has table metric label. Well, I will try several changes but I think your answer is showing the right path.

Thanks!

Comment: As you can see in my edited answer it also works fine with that metric: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmDII.png