# Stackdriver custom label usage in email alerts for metric conditions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

In **Stackdriver**, I am trying to incorporate labels, or specific data values from logs, in email alert documentation, eg error message. I have included the metric selected in Aggregation as well. But they still throw null outputs.
Are there any other settings that need to be checked. I tried following variables\labels in the formats specified while updating policy documentation of metric email alerts - `${metric.label.errortext} (errortext - label)`

```
${metric.label.query}(query - label)
```

Metric variables

```
${protoPayload.serviceData.jobInsertRequest.resource.jobConfiguration.query.query}

${severity}

${metric.label.severity}
```

Above all are returning null value.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the document(s) you were using when setting up your custom label usage in email alerts for metric conditions?

Comment: Can you try with `metric.labels` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59454129/6121516)?

Comment: @AnthonyLeo I found logs on gcp site to be most useful - https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui#documentation

Comment: @GuillemXercavins  Here's a list I tried.  Expect for project id, they give null\error - ${policy.user_label.query} 

Error Message : ${metric.labels.errortext} 
ProjectID :  ${project}
Type 2 : ${protoPayload.serviceData.jobInsertRequest.resource.jobConfiguration.query.query}
Type 3 : ${resource.labels.errortext}
Type 3.1 : ${label.query}
Type 3.3 : ${labels.errortext}
Type 3.4 : ${metric.labels.query}
Type 4: ${errortext}
Type 7: ${severity}
Type 7.1: ${metric.label.severity}
Type 8 : ${metric.label.protoPayload.serviceData.jobInsertRequest.resource.jobConfiguration.query.query}

Comment: @GuillemXercavins I had actually referred to your solution earlier to check for a fix, as you can see from the list I have shared.  errortext\query are my custom labels defined during metric creation when a scheduled BQ query fails.  Those are not getting picked up.  At the least I want to include the failing BQ query in the mail text documentation.  Much thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you exposing the fields as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59760010/6121516)?

Comment: @GuillemXercavins yes that is done as well.  I have incorporated errortext, query, as part of Group By clause in Metric definition.  Do inform if any specific changes to be made.

Comment: As viewed by you and @GuillemXercavins, it would seem that you are implementing custom labels usage in email alerts for metric conditions correctly. I would suggest looking at GCPs official documentation (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels) on creating Logs-based metrics labels for more information regarding this topic.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyLeo.  But I have pretty much read through every available doc. piece available on Metric labels.  For a condition where you define a custom label, for a specific log entry, I am unable to find any demonstration of how to pull that entry in Policy alert documentation.  Only ones working are the pre-defined labels.  Hence looking for some inputs.

Comment: Hey again, I have found an interesting documentation (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables) on variables and channel-specific controls that are available for used with alerting policies. I would suggesting reading the notes that were posted on that document as is could explain why you are receiving null values.

Answer (score 1):

So after multiple tries, I finally figured out the source of the issue.  Alerting with custom labels, needs to be grouped, as obviously, unless grouped you cannot be having alerts within specific time spaces with same label data.   To a certain extent its like SQL group by clause parameters, should be existing in Select as well.
Anyways, the answer was pretty much there in the previous posts-

1. Create your log based metric, and label your target parameter say X

2. Create the alerting policy

3. In conditions, add the Metric created.  Note, importantly the Group By clause needs to include label X.

4. I found using aggregate 'sum' to best suite my requirement, of receiving alerts for every occurrence of the log metric.  I am not clear on the other aggregate params, and how effective they are.

6. For configuration I have used Any time series Violation

7. In policy document, when including the said label, it should be in the form `${metric.label.X}`

Add Notification channels, and let it run.  This is working perfectly for my requirement now.